# how to avoid printk log dropping in linux kernel

Tags: logging, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, printk

Is there any tips or method to avoid kernel log drop or log buffer overrun ?

I have increased the log buffer size to maximum with below code change. I'm running in high end device only. But, still when when i want to get the complete log from my driver(which writes heavy logs), I see the printk logs are dropped sometimes. I use printk with KERN_INFO, gets enabled through dynamic debug(dprintk).

**Change i do:**

```
--- a/kernel/printk.c
+++ b/kernel/printk.c
@@ -55,7 +55,7 @@ void asmlinkage __attribute__((weak)) early_printk(const char *fmt, ...)
 {
 }

-#define __LOG_BUF_LEN  (1 << CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT)
+#define __LOG_BUF_LEN  (1 << 17)
```

**Command i use to write into a file:**

```
cat "/proc/kmsg">/sdcard/klog.txt
```

Only While debugging, I'm okay if the performance is degraded in my driver but, i don't want  drop any logs. I understand we can't make work queues/threads to wait until printing completes. But, still is there any way to get guaranteed that, logs are not dropped.

Comment: `# tail -f /var/log/messages > /tmp/tmplog.txt &` is one simple way to get around this.

Answer (score 5):

Easy, just add "**printk.synchronous=1**" to kernel cmdline.

The printk() has became completely async now. You can add printk.synchronous=1 to let printk() be sync.

Refer to the patch "printk: Make printk() completely async":

> Currently, printk() sometimes waits for message to be printed to
>   console and sometimes it does not (when console_sem is held by some
>   other process). In case printk() grabs console_sem and starts printing
>   to console, it prints messages from kernel printk buffer until the
>   buffer is empty. When serial console is attached, printing is slow and
>   thus other CPUs in the system have plenty of time to append new
>   messages to the buffer while one CPU is printing. Thus the CPU can
>   spend unbounded amount of time doing printing in console_unlock(). 
>   This is especially serious problem if the printk() calling
>   console_unlock() was called with interrupts disabled.
>
> In practice users have observed a CPU can spend tens of seconds
>   printing in console_unlock() (usually during boot when hundreds of
>   SCSI devices are discovered) resulting in RCU stalls (CPU doing
>   printing doesn't reach quiescent state for a long time), softlockup
>   reports (IPIs for the printing CPU don't get served and thus other
>   CPUs are spinning waiting for the printing CPU to process IPIs), and
>   eventually a machine death (as messages from stalls and lockups append
>   to printk buffer faster than we are able to print). So these machines
>   are unable to boot with serial console attached. Another observed
>   issue is that due to slow printk, hardware discovery is slow and udev
>   times out before kernel manages to discover all the attached HW. Also
>   during artificial stress testing SATA disk disappears from the system
>   because its interrupts aren't served for too long.
>
> This patch makes printk() completely asynchronous (similar to what
>   printk_deferred() did until now). It appends message to the kernel
>   printk buffer and wake_up()s a special dedicated kthread to do the
>   printing to console. This has the advantage that printing always
>   happens from a schedulable contex and thus we don't lockup any
>   particular CPU or even interrupts. Also it has the advantage that
>   printk() is fast and thus kernel booting is not slowed down by slow
>   serial console. Disadvantage of this method is that in case of crash
>   there is higher chance that important messages won't appear in console
>   output (we may need working scheduling to print message to console).
>   We somewhat mitigate this risk by switching printk to the original
>   method of immediate printing to console if oops is in progress.
>
> Async printk, for the time being, is considered to be less reliable
>   than the synchronous one, so by default we keep printk operating in
>   synchronous mode. There is a printk.synchronous kernel parameter which
>   permits to select sync/async mode as a boot parameter or later on from
>   user space via sysfs knob.
>
> printk() is expected to work under different conditions and in
>   different scenarios, including corner cases of OOM when all of the
>   workers are busy (e.g. allocating memory), thus printk() uses its own
>   dedicated printing kthread, rather than relying on workqueue (even
>   with WQ_MEM_RECLAIM bit set we potentially can receive delays in
>   printing until workqueue declares a ->mayday, as noted by Tetsuo
>   Handa).

Answer (score 1):

Two ways :

1. `cat /proc/kmsg > some file location &`
2. This is more elaborate :
   Since logging is excessive, don't use `dmesg` buffer at all ?

A> During your drivers init, allocate separate buffer space for logging of desired size (large buffer)

B> Create a separate function to log it say `my_log_buf("Debug check point 1");` that logs in to the aforementioned buffer

C> Give a read system interface and read it using cat /sys/(some exposed interface)